# Editing the Autocomplete term widget(tagging)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

[image: Drupal 7 Website. Customize the links under "Tags"]
Screenshot 1: I want to make the links under "Tags" to customize its HTML not just  tag.
    Mobile

[image: Drupal 7 Website. Using website inspector]
Screenshot 2: The complete markup of "Tags" starting from  with a class of "field-name-field-tags"

From the screenshots above, I want to customize the HTML markup for the autocomplete term widget(tagging) or just this particular field that I made. Where can I find the source file for this? Or how can I modify using a php script alter or related for drupal 7? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To customize HTML markup for all fields taxonomy reference, you can use a **custom template**. To affect term reference field, you can copy the `field.tpl.php` from the core and make a file called `field--taxonomy-reference--yourcontenttype.tpl.php` (if you want to target only one content-type).

To apply your customization **only to "tags"** vocabulary (or/and "category" for example), you can test in a `template_preprocess_field()` function (added to your `template.php`) if you're in a "tags field" to use a custom template called `field--taxonomy-custom.tpl.php` (based on `field.tpl.php` as well). Example :

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  $field_names = array('field-name-field-tags', 'other-field-you-want', 'etc');

  if(in_array($element['#field_name'], $field_names) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = array('field__taxonomy-custom');
  }
}
```

Hope it helped :-)